# Can we lock the computer apps so only browser can be used?

Tags: windows, linux, blocking, restrictions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get Linux into 'Party/Kiosk-Mode' like status?](https://superuser.com/questions/54199/can-i-get-linux-into-party-kiosk-mode-like-status)

People can go on `http://www.example.com` using Firefox - and I will max the screen. I don't want them to navg any website, and taskbar, folder all won't appear, except browser. The PC is touch screen, so imagine this is a self-check-out (retail) browser application.

Is there ulility built-in in Windows 7 and / Linux already? Any mature and recommended 
utility?  I know how to manage the ban list for browsing.

I read this already, and doesn't seem to fit my need fully.
[Lock down PC so only a few programs can be used?](https://superuser.com/questions/116054/lock-down-pc-so-only-a-few-programs-can-be-used)

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "kiosk" mode.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/36845/internet-kiosk-for-motel-lobby, http://superuser.com/questions/120294/firefox-3-6-kiosk-mode, http://superuser.com/questions/48012/whats-the-best-way-to-set-up-kiosk-mode-for-xp

Answer (score 0):

My personal tip: http://webconverger.com/

The author takes donations for a custom build, but you can do it by yourself if you are aware with linux. Anyway, you can almost edit everything by building the bootable CD by yourself, like the startpage, the desktop background or the hostname. I've tested webconverger v7.2 against [iKAT](http://ikat.ha.cked.net/) and it passed it. It has a wide community on google groups, and the updates are recently. It's open source, free and stable.

One small thing i've to admit. If you have physical access to the keyboard at the bootup, you can log in as root without a doubt.

Comment: expand your answer, why should we use that software/solution?